# How to apply full height to a splash screen in iPhoneX - Storyboard

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, mobile

I'm trying to apply a full height to the following splash screen

[image]

But it doesn't work even by setting all the imagens constraints to 0

Maybe is something related with the safe area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the `graphical representation` what you need to do. You need to add `constraint` from `superview` not from `safe area`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to ignore the `safe area insets`. Besides the constraint value that you're setting in the image, there is down arrow from the menu you getting by pressing the down arrow select super view and you'll get the result you need.

[image: safe area]

Note: Do this for both top and bottom to make it full screen. Also, don't forget to remove the existing constraints if you've already created them.